# Have some questions about limit comparison test.

Tags: limits

I have two questions related with limit comparison test.

1. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^c}{n!} $ converges for any $c > 0$
2. $c > 0$: $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^cr^n $ converges $\iff|r| < 1$

How can I prove this problems?

Actually in $1)$ I've solved the case when $c = 1$ and $0 < c < 1$

$$c = 1 \implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^c}{n!}  = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n-1!} \le \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{n-2}} $$

this is convergent series.

$$0 < c < 1\implies {a_n} = \frac{n^c}{n!} \;\text{and}\; {b_n} = (n-1)!$$

then by the limit comparison test, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^c}{n!}$ is convergent.

But when $c>1$ case, I couldn't find any other suitable sequences for conducting limit convergent sequence.

How can I find it?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first one we can compare by [LCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_comparison_test) with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^2}$ since $\forall c\in\mathbb R$

$$\frac{\frac{n^c}{n!}}{\frac{1}{n^2}} =\frac{n^{c+2}}{n!} \to 0$$

we can conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^c}{n!}$ converges.

For the second one $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^cr^n$ we can consider $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^c|r|^n$ and compare with $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |r|^{\frac n2}$ since

$$\frac{n^c|r|^n}{|r|^{\frac n2}} =n^c|r|^{\frac n2} \to 0$$

we can conclude that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^cr^n$ converges.

Comment: Wow thank you very much clear proof!!!

Comment: I have another questions about your answers. How can I prove that $ \frac{n^c}{n!} -> 0$ ??? Please let me know about that.... Thank you!

Comment: For example, a nice way is by ratio test.